# Turning off battery management on desktop

Tags: 12.04, power-management, bluetooth, suspend

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Optiplex GX280 desktop computer. When I hook up my bluetooth mouse and keyboard it seems to recognize their batteries as the actual battery of the computer. As if the desktop were a laptop and it had to worry about the battery levels.

Ubuntu will only stay running for a couple minutes, then I get an error about the battery level being critically low and it goes into suspend mode. I have already tried changing the value in gconf-editor of the critical battery action to "Nothing" , but this doesn't seem to work. The computer still shuts down, which is extremely anoying.

Is there anyway to turn off the power manager for the batteries or delete the critically low monitor?

Comment: Ended up installing 12.10 instead of 12.04. The computer isn't shutting down anymore, but it is still recognizing the bluetooth mouse and keyboard batteries as a laptop battery.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. It makes no sense to suspend the *computer* when the *mouse* is low on battery. Please could you check for an existing bug and mark yourself as affected, or file a new bug if you can't find an existing one?

Comment: I can confirm this bug. I also have a bluetooth keyboard connected to my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit machine.
The keyboard is also recognized as Laptop battery! Especially when I switch my keyboard off, linux instantly shuts down because of a low battery status. btw: gnome-power-manager isn't installed

Answer (score 1):

All those will be listed and worked as selected in Ubuntu through `gnome-power-manager`package. If you remove that package then It will erase those configurations too .

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-power-manager
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Tried this and it is still shutting down after the battery is detected as being critically low. I am going to try and mess around with the gconf-editor to see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge gnome-power-manager` may be?